# how to control quartz scheduler from running using spring & weblogic deployment plan

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, weblogic12c

> i have a quartz scheduler configured with spring, it has five triggers
>   that trigger appropriate jobs. what i am looking for is to have flag
>   that i can use to disable the jobs in dev and test environments and
>   enable in production. below is configuration  in my
>   applicationContext.xml for quartz Scheduler.

```
 <!-- ====================================================================== -->
            <!-- ========================== QUARTZ SCHEDULER ========================== -->
            <!-- ====================================================================== --> 
            <bean id="quartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
             <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
                <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
                <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
                <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>
                <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
                <property name="triggers">
                    <list>
                        <!-- if you remove a trigger, make sure you
                            also remove the trigger 
                            from the QRTZ_TRIGGERS table. 
                        -->
                        <ref bean="Trigger1" />
                        <ref bean="Trigger2" />
                        <ref bean="Trigger3" />
                        <ref bean="Trigger4"/>
                        <ref bean="Trigger5"/>
                    </list>
                </property>
                <property name="quartzProperties">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">ClusteredScheduler</prop>
                        <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
                        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
                        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
                        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.weblogic.WebLogicOracleDelegate</prop>
                        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">qrtz_</prop>
                        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
                        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">20000</prop>
                        <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
                        <!-- Set to 7 to correspond to the 7 nightly jobs that run in the morning -->
                        <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">7</prop>
                        <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
                    </props>
              </property>
            </bean>
```

> Cron Trigger :

```
<bean id="Trigger1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean" scope="prototype">
        <property name="jobDetail">
            <bean name="nightlyJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
                <property name="jobClass" value="My custom class that extends QuartzJobBean"/>
                <property name="group" value="nightly"/>
                <property name="requestsRecovery" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- Cron expression to run job every 10 minutes for testing -->
        <!-- <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/10 * * * ?"/> -->
        <!-- Cron expression that runs at 2:10AM -->
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 10 2 * * ?"/>
    </bean>
```

> What i tried : I tried setting the cron expression to feb31, so that
>   it will never run, but that requires a code change or a script to be
>   run in the database.
>       What i need : need a  flag in my weblogic deployment plan that will turn on or off quartz scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to prevent all jobs from firing, cannot you just leave the scheduler in a stopped state on configured environments (i.e use autoStartup=false on dev/test and autoStartup=true on prod)? It is not actually clear to me how you start your scheduler on prod, because you already seem to have autoStart=false.

If the above is a no go, you have several options:

1. Separate (partial) Spring contexts with the schedulerBean for individual environments. Contexts for dev/test would contain empty job/trigger lists. Then you can use Spring profiles to pick the applicable context based on whatever condition you can think of (e.g. a domain suffix if you use *.devel/*.test/*.prod, some config value, JVM sys property etc.)
2. Implement SchedulerListener and make its schedulerStarted method pause the entire scheduler, or pause all job groups on dev/test.
3. Implement a TriggerListener and make its vetoJobExecution always return true for dev/test and false for prod.

BTW: If you want a visual tool to help you with pausing/unpausing schedulers, jobs and triggers etc., check out [QuartzDesk](http://www.quartzdesk.com). Disclaimer: I am the principal developer of this tool.

Comment: Thanks jan for your response.I am new to quartz scheduling, as per my understanding the scheduler is kicked off based on CRON triggers. I already tried option 3, what i am looking for is a flag that  enables or disables scheduler. i should be able to do that without making any code changes or going through a fresh deployment.

Comment: How do you actually start the scheduler? I ask, because you have autoStart=false which means the scheduler should not be started unless you start it elsewhere? I am thinking that you could simply use Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer that loads different properties files for individual environments so that you can then use: <property name="autoStartup" value="${quartz.autoStart}" />. quartz.autoStart can then be a JVM system property, or it can be a property located in a properties file loaded by the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: // from spring documentation
setAutoStartup :Set whether to automatically start the scheduler after initialization.Default is "true"; set this to "false" to allow for manual startup. i interpret manual startup as configuring triggers to kick off the scheduler to run at certain times. I could be wrong here.

Comment: Rohith, no it is not like so. Triggers do not kick off the scheduler to run at certain times. Triggers are used to kick off jobs. The scheduler is a component that is either running (your triggers kick off jobs), paused (your triggers are paused and do not kick off jobs), or stopped (nothing is happening inside the scheduler, no jobs are ever triggered).

Comment: problem solved: Thanks for the clarification, My application starts scheduler in a servletcontextlistener class, i created a flag in there which gets overidden by weblogic deployment plan.